# Snowflake SQL convert date 'YYYY-MM-DD' to 'DD-MM-YYYY'

Tags: sql, date, type-conversion, format, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in which date is stored in a dimension table.
I am using this table to retrieve the latest reporting week.

```
SELECT MAX("Week") AS "Date" FROM "DWH"."DimWeek"
```

This returns a table with the following date that is in 'YYYY-MM-DD'

```
+--------------------+
| Date               |
|--------------------+
| 2017-01-03         |
+--------------------+
```

I wish to convert this date, so it returns a format of 'DD-MM-YYYY'

I have attempted to use

```
SELECT TO_DATE(MAX("Week"), 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS "Date" FROM "DWH"."DimWeek"

SQL Error
too many arguments for function [TO_DATE(MAX("Week", 'DD-MM-YYYY')] expected 1, got 2
```

I have also attempted to convert it to CHAR

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(MAX("Week")), 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS "Date" FROM "DWH"."DimWeek"
```

However this also returns the result in the undesired format

```
+--------------------+
| Date               |
|--------------------+
| 2017-01-03         |
+--------------------+
```

Any tips or ideas? Currently querying from Snowflake SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `TO_CHAR()`.  You want a *string* in the result, not a *date*:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(MAX("Week")), 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS Date
FROM "DWH"."DimWeek"
```